# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime error - Assertion Failed

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, webdriver-io

Using: VS Code
Working on: Running automation test scripts for WebdriverIO.
Error facing:

[image]

because of this error, my test specs are not executing. Is there any way to get rid of this??

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps to resolve this issue

1. Uninstall the current version of node.js.
2. Go to https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/
3. Install the previous version of node.js (I installed from here 4.
   https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-x64.msi)
4. Restart your system
5. Try building the project using npm install

I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The error here is coming from the Fibers npm package. Fibers only supports node versions before version 16. I had the same error message and switched the node version  to 14.20.0 ,which is the newest LTS before version before 16 at the moment, and that solved the problem for me.